# Preferred way to add Maps to a List?

Tags: list, elixir

I've been trying to learn Elixir for a few days and I'm wondering if there is a better/preferred way of adding maps to a collection. For example, I'm working with a `photos` list that contains many `photo` maps.  I am adding new maps using `Enum.concat(photos, photo)`.

However, I am trying to look at the documentation and I am probably missing something obvious. Is there a better way to add a `photo` to `photos` instead of:

```
photos = Enum.concat(photos, photo)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enum.concat/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#concat/2) is just one of many ways you can insert an item into a list. You can also use the shorthand `++` operator:

```
photos = photos ++ [photo]
```

---

If the order does not matter to you, you can also prepend your `photo` at the start of the list; it's much faster performance wise (`O(1)` compared to `O(n)`).

```
photos = [ photo | photos ]
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  I knew about `++` but it seemed a little strange to me since you have to make sure to wrap the variable in brackets.  I appreciate the bit about faster performance op as well.